# Phonegap build Error code 65

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using adobe phone gap build (https://build.phonegap.com) and i get this error:

> === BUILD TARGET Firstapp OF PROJECT Firstapp WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
>
> Check dependencies Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning
>   Profile: com.OgonLabs.test2" is Xcode managed, but signing settings
>   require a manually managed profile. Code signing is required for
>   product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'
>
> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  Check dependencies (1 failure)
>   Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/private/project/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-workspace,Firstapp.xcworkspace,-scheme,Firstapp,-configuration,Release,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,Firstapp.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/private/project/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/private/project/build/sharedpch

I generate my .p12 certificate and then I make an app with id = "com.myCompany.test2" in Xcode and i generate provisioning profile. The same id has phonegap app. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Remove another account added in your Xcode After that build with latest Provisioning Profile. and also check download all latest profile and certificate from xcode->windows->organizer->select account and download all certificate.